# Relate ratios to sample size

Tags: descriptive-statistics, odds-ratio, ratio

suppose to have the following situation:
you have a total number of deaths equal to 120. Of them, 20 individuals had cancer. The ratio is 20/120 = 0.16. The total individuals with cancer was 320. How can you relate 0.16 (i.e., the ratio) to the size 320 of all patients with cancer?

Thank you in advance